# Environment variables in Weblogic Managed Server with SSL nodemanager

Tags: java, environment-variables, weblogic

We have a C legacy application start with JNI that requires environment variables. Not java -Djava.library.path -Dvar=foo as these are purely java. I need real environment variables.

When we setup our domains, we usually use the SSH method to start the node managers. This works fine and the env variables are set properly.

Recently the sysadmin has decided for a few reasons to use the SSL mode for nodemanagers. The servers start but the environment variables are not set.

I checked with "pargs -e" (this is a Solaris machine) that the env variable was indeed not present from the nodemanager and for the managed server.

Is SSL starting the managed server without running the .sh scripts or I am missing a parameter somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the nodemanager.properties file, one can define:

```
StartScriptEnabled=true
```

And restart the node manager.

This also raised errors because grep, uname and expr were not in the path. We added the path to the script.